# Creating Unit Tests for ViewModels

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, viewmodel

I have recently completed this (links below) codelabs tutorial which walks through how to implement Room with LiveData and Databinding in Kotlin.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/

https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/kotlin

Following on from this, I want to write some tests around the ViewModel, however, the GitHub repository where the code is stored does not contain any (it has a few tests around the DAO, not what I am interested in for now).

The ViewModel I am trying to test looks like this:

```
class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: WordRepository
    // Using LiveData and caching what getAlphabetizedWords returns has several benefits:
    // - We can put an observer on the data (instead of polling for changes) and only update the
    //   the UI when the data actually changes.
    // - Repository is completely separated from the UI through the ViewModel.
    val allWords: LiveData<List<Word>>

    init {
        val wordsDao = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).wordDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordsDao)
        allWords = repository.allWords
    }

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insert(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repository.insert(word)
    }
}
```

My test class for the ViewModel looks like this:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class WordViewModelTest {
    private val mockedApplication = mock<Application>()

    @Test
    fun checkAllWordsIsEmpty() {
        val vm = WordViewModel(mockedApplication)
        assertEquals(vm.allWords, listOf<String>())
    }
}
```

I get an error saying `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot provide null context for the database.` This error then points to this line in the WordViewModel: `val wordsDao = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).wordDao()`. To get this to not crash, I believe I need to mock a lot of what is in the ViewModel, which I am fine with.

I would like to be able to run the test above and in the future, I would also like to mock return a list of data when `repository.allWords` is called. However, I am not sure how to do this. So my question is, how can I mock the following lines from WordViewModel to allow me to do this?

```
val wordsDao = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).wordDao()
repository = WordRepository(wordsDao)
allWords = repository.allWords
```

Comment: Unit test runs on pure java virtual machine. You can test room implementation on real device, emulator device or using Robolectric, simulated android machine.

Comment: Im not wanting to test Room here, I am just wanting to test the ViewModel through mocking.